# catkin_make_isolated ignore package

Tags: ros, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

is there a way to specify some packages to ignore while invoking `catkin_make_isolated` ?? I'm looking for some command line option, I already know about `CATKIN_IGNORE`.
I tried `-DCATKIN_BLACKLIST_PACKAGES` as I would when using `catkin_make` but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks.

Edit: Couldn't find anything, thus opened [catkin #1027](https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1027).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/330717/catkin_make_isolated-ignore-package/) by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2019-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-08-15**:
cool for fixing this :-) This is worth a self-answer that you can accept :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I couldn't find anything to blacklist packages while invoking `catkin_make_isolated`, I added a blacklist option - see
[catkin #1027](https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1027).

Use :  `catkin_make_isolated --ignore-pkg foo bar`

---

Originally posted by [artivis](https://answers.ros.org/users/11816/artivis/) with karma: 65 on 2019-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0